# Variable sharing tensorflow

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network

**Background**

While going through the documentation of tensorflow,I came across the convolutional neural net example on the [Variable Sharing](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/how_tos/variable_scope/).The examples motivates the need of variable sharing by describing a problem in which two images are exposed to image filter which would want to reuse the variables.

**Problem**

I am not able to get my head around this approach.Instead of introducing concept of variable sharing can we not place all the images in a matrix(in form of pixel values with each row denoting a new image) and perform necessary operations like filters on the whole matrix by using single set of variables.The approach I am suggesting is similar to what we use in vanilla neural networks.We dont use the concept of reusing variables for every training example rather we stack them up in form of matrix and have a common weight matrix for all the training examples to perform the necessary operations.

Can someone point where am I wrong in setting up the congruency between the two approaches?

Answer (score 0):

In the forward pass, you can't distinguish between a shared variable and two identical variables. But in training, the backward pass is different. If you had two identical variables, you'll have two adjustments, and those will in general not be identical so the two variables will diverge. If you have a single shared variable, you have only a single adjustment.

Comment: Thanks for response!But I really cannot find a reason for reusing variables in case of images when we dont do it in vanilla neural networks.In vanilla network,we have input matrix made up of all training examples(similarly we can have input matrix with all images) and a common weight matrix(similarly we can have common filter).When this approach works in training of vanilla nets then why not in the case of images with convolution networks?